# Width and margin auto to center not working

Tags: css, width, block, center, margins

I looked up how to center a block in the middle of the screen and I read that I had to specify width to a value and margins to auto.

```
<head>
<style>
#CenteredBlock {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: visible;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-top-style: dotted;
    border-right-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-left-style: dotted;
    border-top-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-left-color: #000;
    padding: 0%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="CenteredBlock" id="CenteredBlock"> Test </div>
</body>
```

I want the block to occupy 70% of the screen, centered, left and right are suposed to have 15%. If I use margin-left: 15%; and same for right then the block centers but still I want to know why isn't it centering when I specified width and margins:auto

Answer (score 0):

You don't want #CenteredBlock absolutly positioned. You want it 'centered'. So, remove "position:absolute" and all will work fine.

Comment: (Since I can't answer my question right now I'll post a comment) Ok, now the problem is making the block start from the "zeroest" pixel on top possible. Right now it leaves a white gap between the block and the browser bar! :P

Comment: This new problem it is not originated in the #CenteredBlock div. That gap appears because of the browser default styles. All browser add some CSS to composition, that's why we use reset style sheets. 

So, to solve this new issue you can use a reset.css (there's a lot of options all around the internet) or reset directly those who are in conflict with your layout. 

I bet, that adding: 

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

would make disappear the gap.

Comment: Ya, in the other question I asked someone replied that too. I could've waited for you to answer I guess ^_^" Thanks anyway!